# How to Enable HSTS in Play framework 2.3.x using scala code?

Tags: scala, ssl, playframework-2.3, hsts, strict-transport-security

I have a Play Framework 2.3.6 version app running on Sbt, using Sbt SSL endpoint with scala coding...

I would like to see the (hsts)strict transport security response in the headers.

I am trying locally in postman using the URL http ://localhost:9000

How to write the code?

**What's the best way to that?** for play 2.3

I searched in play blog and understood that Redirection filters are supported on 2.6 and above, but I am using only 2.3.x version.

Is there any best solution provided to test locally in postman using HTTP . so that I can see the hsts headers in the response.

Note : I have HTTP blocked in production mode. I can use only https in production.

Comment: @users, can anybody help here i am stuck on this task

Comment: Note that , i do not have a proxy server for my application , so cannot set x-forwarded-proto , is there any other way i can find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your application.conf:

```
play.filters.https.strictTransportSecurity="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
```

You can use curl request to check the same:

```
curl -s -D- https://localhost:9000/{{api}} | grep -i Strict
```

Reference: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9711/38/how-to-check-if-hsts-is-enabled